# Return a 404 or other error code from GWT

Tags: gwt

I'm working on handling history within my GWT application. 
If, during the History.ValueChanged event, the history tag value is unknown,
I'd like to show the user a 404.

How can I return a standard "Page Not Found" from GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URL tokens (the part after the `#`) are not sent to the server - changes to that URL part don't create an HTTP request, so there is no HTTP response, and hence no HTTP error code.

(Of course you can react to URL token changes from within your History's ValueChangeHanler, and manually trigger an HTTP request - which could then return a 404. But to show that 404 to the user, you'd have to relocate to that URL, which is probably not what you want. How about showing a nice error message to the user instead?)

Comment: ah, this makes perfect sense. Thanks.